# How to save the activity form fields when switching to another activity and coming back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activity **MainActivity** and **AddressActivity**. In **MainActivity** i have three editText views and one TextView. on TextView i have put an onclick which starts another Activity AddressActivity.

- In AddressActivity I am getting the address from google map.
- After getting the address from the user I am setting this address onto the TextView in MainActivity

Now the problem is when i am coming back to the MainActivity from AddressActivity the EditText field in MainActivity are getting reset. Instead i want is whatever the user has set in the Edittext it should remain there.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 public void openAddress(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AddressActivity.class));
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#20ffffff">
           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Give a title"
                />
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Give description"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/issue_map_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Exact Address"
                android:onClick="openAddress"/>
               <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="onsubmit"
               />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AddressActivity.java**

```
public class AddressActivity extends Activity{
   // Async call
   // IN this way i am sending the address string to the Main Activity
   @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AddressActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("address", userAddress.toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }   
}
```

The problem is data from AdressActivity get set into the MainActivity but all the EditText also gets reset.
I want to maintain the entered the EditText data ... How to go about it...

Comment: u r stairng new MainActivity or first u save value in priference and than use it

Comment: you are using startactivity for result to get the result from address activity or you are starting main activity again from address activity

Comment: @MeenalSharma From MainActivity on textView onclick i am starting adressActivity and from there i am passing the address values to mainActivity

Comment: Do you get results in onActivityResult of MainActivity when came back from AddressActivity??

Comment: Yes i am getting it and i am able to set also ... but problem My other editText fields are getting reset like title and description

Comment: if you restart the activity they will get reset..if not then they will not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

public void openAddress(View view) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, AddressActivity.class),123);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("address"));

}

}
```

and for Address activity

```
public class AddressActivity extends Activity{
    // Async call
   // IN this way i am sending the address string to the Main Activity
   @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
                 Intent intent = getIntent();  
                intent.putExtra("address",userAddress.toString());  

                setResult(123,intent);             
               finish();

 }
```

Comment: I am not able to send the data to MainActivity.. Means on button click in MapActivity i am making async call but it not going to MainActivity... Is the Intent is correct or i need to pass some arguments like activity class.

Comment: replace Intent intent=new Intent();  line of code by Intent intent = getIntent(); it will work.

Comment: I am getting back to the MainActivity but the onActivityResult() doesn't get's call I dont know why.

Comment: have you call address activity with startactivityresult and the code is same

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your `onCreate` in `MainActivity` :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if(data != null)
{
   address = data.getString("address");
   myEditText.setText(address);
}
```

The problem is you have sent the "address" : `i.putExtra("address", userAddress.toString());`, but you dont take it. The aboves code is to take the "address" value.

Comment: No i have done this part, I am able to set the address string in my MainActivity but other EditText fields are getting empty...

Comment: Its because you just send one String ("address"). Where is the other String? And please update your code, your code in your question shows you do nothing with the intent in MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

@
anand you have to use sharedpreference for the same.....you can save the edittext value in shared preferences and load preferences in onCreate method of MainActivity.......for more help follow this link...
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

You can also do it in other way...as @MeenalSharma  explained......